# How to call back new variable in between array objects using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I want to call back new variable (section) after 3 objects called from array. I tried that using JavaScript Es6 Map but not getting exact result can somebody please help. Thanks in advance. Below I attached my code

```
const array = [
{
 id:1,
 name:'naren'
},
{
 id:2,
 name:'naren2'
},
{
 id:3,
 name:'naren3'
},
{
 id:4,
 name:'naren4'
},
{
 id:5,
 name:'naren5'
},
{
 id:6,
 name:'naren6'
},
{
 id:7,
 name:'naren7'
}
{
 id:8,
 name:'naren8'
}
]

//New Section
const section = 'New section';
```

Expected Output Result in console

```
Ouput :

naren1
naren2
naren3
New Section
naren4
naren5
naren6
naren7
naren8
```

Comment: You just want to split the array?

Comment: but how to call back next function after split  also i want done it through without duplicate call

Comment: It's very unclear what you're talking about. I think you need to give a better example and show what you've tried. From what you've posted here, it looks like you just need to split an array, print the first part, print "New Section", then print the second part.

Comment: yes right print first part then call New section after that i dont want to print second part .. i want to result should come from first part.. using map concept we can split  array.slice(0,3).map( data => { console.log(data.name) ; then new section ; then call pending array objects here })

Answer (score 0, accepted):

loop over the array and check the index, this should produce your desired output

```
array.forEach((el, index) => index === 3 
  ? console.log(el.name + '\n' + section) 
  : console.log(el.name))
```

Comment: working but suppose if array length was below 3 not able to call new section. new section not comming. also why we need print console.log(el.name) two times . suppose i f i want to do any changes its realy difficult to apply both place

Comment: while using index < 3 new section returning 3 times